# Jplot meter gauge chart with multiple needles

Tags: jqplot

I have implemented meter guage chart it is working fine. I want multiple needles on the same meter. Is that possible?

For Ex: if we have

```
s1 = [122,80]; or s1 = [122,80];s2 = [200];
```

in this case can we get multiple needles but on the same meter.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no. Like you, I have tried a number of things, but the normal approach to the series would be:

```
s1 = [122];s2 = [200];
series = [s1, s2];

plot = $.jqplot('chart',series,{ ... });
```

... but this is clearly not working. And I couldn't find such a thing in the documentation either.
I hope it becomes available in a future release too.